# When piping input from one program to another, what happens to the original program if the program receiving output is killed?

Tags: output, kill, pipe

I am piping the output of a program like this using bash:

```
program1 | program2
```

If program2 is killed somehow (in my case by a PHP fatal error), what happens to the instance of program1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It greatly depends on what `program1` is. The software needs to be able to handle (or ignore) a `SIGPIPE` signal. `program1` will be responsible for handling the error - if the software is open source you should be able to discern what happens or if it traps/detects a `SIGPIPE` signal. If the software doesn't do anything special with streams it will likely complete execution before passing on the results. I attempted a small example to show the point using two php scripts.

#### program1

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

@unlink('program1.out');

for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ )
{
    // This goes to either the buffer or whoever is next in the pipe
    echo $i . PHP_EOL;
    // Put everything in a file so we can see what Program1 actually did
    file_put_contents('program1.out', $i . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);   
}

// All done! Cap off the file
file_put_contents('program1.out', 'Fin', FILE_APPEND);
```

#### program2

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

// We're taking inputs and just redirecting them to program2.out
// but to make it fun I'll throw an error half way through
// because I'm malicious like that

@unlink('program2.out');

$pipe_input = file("php://stdin");
$pipe_total = count($pipe_input);
$stop = rand(0, $pipe_total - 1);

echo "I'll be stopping at $stop" . PHP_EOL;

foreach( $pipe_input as $key => $input )
{
    if( $key == $stop )
    {
        file_put_contents('program2.out', 'Dead!', FILE_APPEND);
        die(1);
    }

    file_put_contents('program2.out', $input, FILE_APPEND);
}
```

When you execute `./program1 | ./program2` you'll get two `.out` files one for each program. In the example I ran I got the following files:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Fin
```

And for `program2.out`

```
0
1
2
3
4
Dead!
```

The first program will execute and pass it's contents to the second. You'll notice that the first program's .out file has a full set of numbers and the second only contains a set of that because it was killed off.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :) Your example only partly relates to my actual problem, which I didn't really discuss in the question (but the use case is probably more spread). I am piping ffmpeg error/info/progress output to a php script, which I am reading char by char, while I think your example reads until EOF. Since ffmpeg will run for hours, I need to know exactly what happens. I think it is terminated by SIGPIPE actually. :)

Comment: @Max In that case it depends on how `ffmpeg` handles `SIGPIPE`. A workaround would be to have `ffmpeg` pipe it's `STDERR` to a file and your php script tail or chunk/process the file that way you don't have long running php files which are not quite optimized for long running execution.

Comment: true, but I am not running PHP it a web-based context. I am using `at` to execute php. :) I actually want to shut-down ffmpeg if something happens during the log-script execution, since I want the execution to be in a known state. But you clarified alot, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

The pipe will be broken and the program writing to the pipe will receive a SIGPIPE signal.

From [GLIBC](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/glibc/libc_477.html):

> SIGPIPE
>       Broken pipe. If you use pipes or FIFOs, you have to design your
>   application so that one process opens
>   the pipe for reading before another
>   starts writing. If the reading process
>   never starts, ***or terminates
>   unexpectedly***, writing to the pipe or
>   FIFO raises a SIGPIPE signal. If
>   SIGPIPE is blocked, handled or
>   ignored, the offending call fails with
>   EPIPE instead.

Comment: What's the default action for something receiving a SIGPIPE signal? Eg if an application doesn't handle it directly, does something else come along and nuke it or will it just carry on pipeless?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing. Data goes to /dev/null. 
P.S. Oh, yes, the program will recieve a signal, but it doesn't mean it will have to close.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that `program1` dies.

`program1` gets a `SIGPIPE` signal when the pipe is broken.  Programs designed to be long running daemons usually handle the signal and do proper cleanup, but your typical interactive program does not.  The default action is to terminate the program, so for the most part, `program1` will just be terminated.